# svn: merging between branches other than trunk

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

We have a SVN project with branch B that I work on, and branch C, that a coworker works on. (he works primarily on one area of code and I work primarily on another)

How are he and I supposed to merge, if we wish to stay in sync prior to doing any merges to the trunk?

We don't have any problems merging content, but the content (particularly svn:mergeinfo, for obvious reasons) keeps displaying tree conflicts and always gives us trouble.

What should we do?

Comment: because he's bleeding-edge (i.e. alpha-status or worse) in his area, and I'm bleeding-edge in my area, and we need to stay separate until we get our respective branches in good shape, at which point we merge again.

Comment: @Vivek: why'd you delete your comment? it was a valid point, but now the context is gone.

Comment: Like I said in your other thread: use svnmerge! (http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py)

Comment: @Jason S , It was having a lot of English mistake. I was looking for edit and by mistake clicked on that cross sign.

Comment: @Vivek -- ah, ok. For what it's worth, don't be worried about your English, it's fine. I'm about 20x more willing to overlook grammatical/spelling errors than I am technical errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you can both work in the same branch then consider doing a baseless merge of all changes to one branch and abandon the other branch. If you have other changes in your branch that must remain separate then CAREFULLY consider cherry-picking just the changes that should be baseless merged to single branch, then revert those changes in the source branch.

Structure (for reference):

- Trunk

  - Branch A
  - Branch B

Process would be something like the following:

1. **FI** (Forward Integrate) Trunk to both children. (Merge Trunk to Branch **A**, then Trunk to Branch **B**).
2. **Baseless merge** from **B** to **A**.
3. Abandon **B** (at very least lock to prevent accidentally using retired branch).
4. **FI** Trunk to **A** again (re-establishing merge relationship and ironing out any merge conflicts before further changes are introduced.
5. Both you and other developer continue developing in branch **A** until stable.
6. **FI** Trunk to **A** (pick up latest changes from other developers or other trunk activity)
7. Quickly build and run smoke tests in A (confirm FI successful and A is still stable)

   1. If More changes to trunk occur during smoke test then repeat 6 & 7 or possibly lock trunk until steps 6 - 8 can be completed.
8. RI (Reverse Integrate) A to Trunk

**IDEA:** If possible avoid having to share unstabilized changes between child branches in the future. Baseless merges and cherry-picking changes are both higher risk operations than standard full parent-child merges. One apprach is to use a common Development branch, then branch by feature only when needed. All developers use the common dev branch for changes. When breaking change needs multiple developers to build&stabilize create the feature branch. Once stabilized integrate back to Dev branch and retire the feature branch.

Comment: +1 for info + effort, though it's not really a convenient way to work.